# SOAP not getting encoded as MTOM in a WCF client

Tags: wcf, mtom, documentum-dfs

I am connecting to a DFS(Documentum Foundation Services) instance from a WCF client. 
I am using basicHttpBinding and I have set the messageEncoding="Mtom". However, when I inspect the soap, I see the document within the SOAP envelop. The document part in the SOAP is about 1.33 times the actual doc size. So the message is getting Base64 encoded.

Do I have more settings to change on the WCF side Or is there a MTOM setting that is not enabled on the DFS side?

Does wsoma:OptimizedMimeSerialization have to be there in the WSDL?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

http://www.w3.org/Submission/WS-MTOMPolicy/

I guess, my question is: does the Java web service WSDL has to have this wsoma:OptimizedMimeSerialization  element, otherwise it implies that the web service does not support MTOM?
Which also implies that if the Java based web service did support MTOM and then if I add a service reference using the WSDL, Visual Studio should automatically create the appropiate binding with messageEncoding="Mtom"??